# Installing cinnamon

Tags: 22.04, cinnamon

To install Cinnamon DE in Ubuntu 22.04 should I install `cinnamon` package or `cinnamon-desktop-environment`?

What is the difference between these two packages?

Comment: Have you looked; ie. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cinnamon&searchon=names&suite=jammy&section=all  where you'll note `cinnamon-desktop-environment` is the "*Cinnamon desktop environment - full desktop with extra components*" and `cinnamon is the "*Innovative and comfortable desktop*" ie. Cinnamon gets the base desktop itself, the other gives a more full experiences with more tools/features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to you.

The full Cinnamon DE is provided by the meta-package `cinnamon-desktop-environment`:

> These are the extended components of Cinnamon, a desktop environment which
> provides advanced innovative features and a traditional user experience.
>
> This metapackage depends on all programs needed to have a fully
> fledged desktop environment. Install this if you want a complete
> cinnamon desktop, including graphical apps that allow users to perform
> almost all everyday tasks.

Whereas `cinnamon` is the basic DE. Either one will install all the required dependencies.

Comment: Is it possible that after installing Cinnamon, the system will have a problem or conflict?

Comment: Installing any additional DE doesn't normally cause problems other than duplication of apps/tools. This in itself seldom causes problems.